# Multiple html pages using Intel App Framework

Tags: appframework

So I have an app that I am trying to strip out all of the JQuery Mobile and now use Intel's App Framework. I am having trouble figuring out how to integrate multiple html pages into the app so that I don't have to have all my code in a single file. I tried this:

```
$.ui.loadContent("page2.html");
```

but that doesn't seem to work. I get a 'loading content' spinner but nothing seems to happen.

How do I link pages together from different files?

Comment: loadContent loads another panel (div), not html file, generally speaking, its troublesome. I have been using it with angular js, and tried to use templates, it worked, but it didnt get along well, views were not rendered properly and I ended up with one big html file..

Comment: Might be too late, but use the div id. If i'm not mistaken without using the hash

Comment: So my entire app needs to be in one html file? That sounds awful to maintain..

Comment: its not THAT bad but would be good if pages could be in separate files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I have figured it out. The documentation can sometimes be hard to search and there is no search box available on their website right now. But if you go to the quickstart and then then AFUI(on the left) and then panel properties they say:

> `data-defer="filename.html"` - This will load content into the panel
>   from a remote page/url. This is useful for separating out content into
>   different files. af.ui.ready is not available until all files are
>   loaded asynchronously.

So in my index.html file I have something like this:

```
<div id="afui">
    <nav>
        <ul class="list">
            <li><a href="#post-lunch_panel" class="icon heart">Post a Lunch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#profile_panel" class="icon user">Personal Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#select-university_panel" class="icon chat">Select University</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>


<!--Main View Pages-->
<div class="panel" title="Events" id="event-list_panel" data-defer="event-list.html" data-load="loadMainEventsList">  </div>

<div class="panel" title="Description" id="description_panel" data-defer="description.html" data-load="loadEventDetails">  </div>

<div class="panel" title="Select University" id="select-university_panel" data-defer="select-university.html">  </div>

</div> <!--id="afui"-->
```

and then I have the details of each page in seperate files. In my mind this does a literal copy/paste, and I haven't found any evidences yet that it isn't just a copy/paste.

**Update:**

in AF3 `data-defer` is now `data-include`

Comment: In AF3 its called data-include, and as described "load content from the HTTP request".